# Syntax highlight operators such as *,->

Tags: c, vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the spf-13 vim distribution on OS X (this problem is not specific to this distribution). I tried a few different color schemes (solarized, default, desert) and none of them highlight C specific operators such as *,->, etc. Further reading showed that this depends on the regex defined to identify these operators. I'm not versed enough in vim script/regex to try this modification yet on a color scheme.

Is it possible to modify solarized or any other scheme to highlight these operators in C? It would be ideal if there is a color scheme that already supports this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colorschemes only define colors for syntax/highlight groups defined in syntax files (and default groups).

Since the default C syntax file doesn't appear to define anything for these operators (or any other, actually) there's nothing you can do to your colorscheme to make them stand out. It's the syntax file that should be mofified… or extended.

[This syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3064) extends the default syntax file with, among other things, operators.